# how to combine the two file by awk

Tags: awk

Here is my `1.file`

```
             id
             a1
             a2
             a3
             a4
```

Here is my `2.file`

```
             DW  1  2  3  4
             KD  2  3  4  5
             LBJ 4  4  4  4
```

I want to get my final file

```
             id  a1 a2 a3 a4
             DW  1  2  3  4
             KD  2  3  4  5
             LBJ 4  4  4  4
```

And I try to

```
cat 1.file |tr "\n" "\t"|sed -e 's/,$/\n/'
```

and then

```
cat 1.file 2.file >> fina.file
```

but I want to get the `awk` way

Comment: don't step down my reputation, please. LOL

Comment: Never use `tr` to convert newlines to some other character and then pipe the result to a different text processing tool because removing all of the newlines turns your text into something that can't reliably be read by any text processing tool as it's now undefined behavior (all text processing tools are only guaranteed to work with valid text file input and a valid text file MUST have a newline at the end. Also see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award - `cat file | cmd` can always be written as either `cmd file` or `cmd < file` for any command `cmd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bash
$ column -t <( paste -s 1.file ) 2.file
id   a1  a2  a3  a4
DW   1   2   3   4
KD   2   3   4   5
LBJ  4   4   4   4
```

The lines of `1.file` are turned into a single line of headers by means of `paste -s` and then `column -t` is used to align these headers with the data in `2.file`.

The above assumes that you are using a shell that understands process substitutions with `<(...)`.  If you are not, then use the following instead:

```bash
paste -s 1.file | column -t /dev/stdin 2.file
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by `I want to get the awk way` you mean you want to learn how to do everything in one awk script:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ hdr=hdr sep $0; sep=OFS; next} FNR==1{ print hdr } 1' 1.file 2.file
id a1 a2 a3 a4
DW  1  2  3  4
KD  2  3  4  5
LBJ 4  4  4  4
```

Comment: Best answer, but doesn't handle the leading whitespace correctly for the header.

Comment: @anick in cases like this there invariably is no leading white space in  the real data, it's just a formatting error in the question. In 40+ years of programming I've never come across real data where every line starts with a bunch of white space that has to be retained.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. But still.

Answer (score 1):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk '{ORS=(NR%5?FS:RS)}1' 1.file >final.file
cat 2.file >>final.file
```

The `awk` code print the 5 consecutive rows as one. And then with `cat` you add the rest of the file

Answer (score 1):

Keep indentation:

```bash
cat <( fmt 1.file ) 2.file
             id a1 a2 a3 a4
             DW  1  2  3  4
             KD  2  3  4  5
             LBJ 4  4  4  4
```